# How to grant some users partial user management rights in Keycloak?

Tags: permissions, keycloak, roles, keycloak-services, idp

Let's say I'm using one realm `mycomp` in Keycloak to handle all users (+ `master` realm for Keycloak superadmin).

I'm have role of Customer Support (CS) that should be able to view users and manage their basic data like names, email, password reset etc.

I'm able to grant `realm-management` permissions like `manage-users` or `view-users` to any user in 3 ways:

- assign directly
- by creating composite role for CS
- by creating group with and adding there CS

The problem is that giving `manage-users` rights CS end up being able to manage roles and groups so it is able to grant other users management permissions. Thats not valid for my config - it is a role of some higher level admin.

**How to grant some users permissions to view and manage basic user data without allowing them to manage roles?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So in the end of the day I finally managed to find an working solution.

Problem was that **Role** `manage-users` cant be overriten by **Policy**.

With help of Pedro Igor Silva from Keycloak (https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-18151) I managed to setup configuration that fullfills the usecase.

With Keycloak preview feature `admin_fine_grained_authz` enabled I created global composite **Role** `user-managers` and granted it `query-users` **Role** from `realm-management` client. Then I created **Policy** that grants `manage` permission on `Users` resource when user has `user-manager` role.

That works perfectly

Comment: FYI @dreamcrash

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about it